# OS/X Mavericks won't download in App Store

Tags: macos, mac

I tried to download OS/X Mavericks through the App Store yesterday.  However, I had to leave work before it was done downloading and shut down the machine while it was downloading.

I assumed I'd be able to resume the download, or start over again later.

However, now there's no way to get it to download again.  When I find OS/X Mavericks in the store, I click on the "Download" link.  It asks for my Apple ID which I enter, and it does absolutely nothing.  It doesn't begin downloading, and it just still shows the "Download" button.  Clicking on it again does nothing.

I'm thinking there's something *stuck* somewhere, like some flag that says this download is in progress or it has already been downloaded.  Is there some way to clear that out so I can start downloading it again?

Comment: Have you checked your Applications folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking your Purchases in the App Store to see if its there, if so you should be able to resume it and/or install it from here if its completed downloading. See https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4485.

You should also be able to clear a download from the Purchases section by clicking the 'X' which would appear next to the 'Status Button' of the item you wish to clear.

For example in the picture below if you hover your mouse over to the left of the 'Downloaded' button a 'X' should appear.

[image]

In your case that Status Button should say 'Resume', you can choose to resume by clicking on it or clearing it by hovering to the left of the button until the 'X' appears.

Failing that, call Apple customer service, they should be able to help.

**EDIT:** try checking for unfinished downloads via the menu bar and signing out/in and retrying the download.

[image: App Store Menu Bar Options]

**EDIT:** try checking and resuming the download in your Launchpad, progress should be shown on/in Launchpad. you can also delete the App in Launchpad by clicking and holding on the App until a close 'X' appears on the App. Then try re-downloading the App from the App Store.

[image: Launchpad download progress]

Comment: It shows up in the list, but doesn't say "Resume".  I hit the "X" button which made it disappear.  However, if I go back in the App Store and try to download it again, it still does nothing..

Comment: Though it is a bit different now.  Now, when I find *OSX Mavericks* in the App Store, it says `Install App` instead of `Download`.  When I click on it, it asks for my Apple ID which I enter.  Then, it does nothing.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - sorry for the late reply, although unlikely to help have you tried this: 1) Checking for unfinished downloads in the App Store menu (see the latest edit to my answer above) 2) Signing out of the App Store altogether and signing back in and repeating the download process.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it didn't fix the issue..

Comment: @MikeChristensen - have you checked your Launchpad? to see if the app is there?

Comment: There is - It says "Paused".  Clicking on it has no effect.

Comment: Actually, I clicked on it a few times and it had no effect, then closed Launch Pad, and now went back in and it says "Downloading" again..  However, I can't really tell if it's *actually* making any progress or just *stuck* on saying Downloading.  I'll report back in 20min or so.

Comment: I wish I could figure out *where* it was downloading the file to, so I could see if the file was getting any bigger.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - For me, the progress was shown in my Launchpad. A small bar should appear showing the download process, see a picture in the edit of my answer above. If nothing happens after a while, there may be a location where the partial file is kept until its moved to the Application folder once it reaches 100%.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - if no progress is made after a while, try deleting the application from Launchpad and download again from the App Store. This link gives info on how to delete apps in Launchpad -> http://www.tothepc.com/archives/open-delete-launchpad-apps-mac-osx-lion/

Comment: That seems to have worked!  It's started downloading again, but *crazy* slow..  About a third done after an hour..  I might have to leave work again before it's done!  Sigh..

Answer (score 2):

Might be a shot in the dark but quit the App Store, open up your terminal and run this:

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app
```

It may have gotten corrupt and cant be overwritten when it tries to download again. Then open your app store back up and give it another shot. Also please be careful. The RM command is a powerful and dangerous tool. You should definitely have good backups :)

Comment: No such file.  I ran the command anyway, and it didn't solve the problem.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hm, Im not sure whats going on then. Have you tried downloading disk doctor from the app store, clear all of the caches and then redownloading? 

If that doesnt work maybe sign out of icloud, reboot, sign back into icloud, reboot and then try redownloading .

Answer (score 0):

From [Partial Maverick OS X download aborted, how to force re-download?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5468406?tstart=0) :

> I was having the same issue, and found a solution that does not
>   require a reboot. Whenever I encounter an error in the Maverick
>   download I,
>
> Step 1: Copy (Cmd+C) the "OSX Mavericks" app package from the
>   **Applications** folder
>
> Step 2: Move (Cmd+Opt+V) it to another folder, say downloads
>
> Step 3: Close Mac App Store
>
> Step 4: Move the "OSX Mavericks" file back to the applications folder
>
> Step 5: Double click "OSX Mavericks" and it resumes the download
>   (rather than starting a fresh new download)

Comment: I don't have anything called *OSX Mavericks" in the `Applications` folder.

Comment: It might be called "Install OS X Mavericks.app". Otherwise you have deleted it by cancelling the download.

Comment: Yup, nothing called `*Mav*` in `/Applications` - I definitely cancelled the download when I turned off the machine, I'm trying to figure out how to start the download again.

Comment: If Apple customer service cannot help, your other option is to find a Mavericks torrent and make yourself an installation dvd or usb, which would be quite legal in your case. Example : thepiratebay dot sx.

Comment: Yea, I might just take it into the store.  Apple Care is expired, so I'm not sure if they'd help me for free.  They also might have install DVDs there, which I can't imagine would be very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the App Store. Search for Mavericks. The little box will only say "Free" and nothing you do will get it to download. Instead, click on the Mavericks link to bring up the whole splash page describing Mavericks. The (larger) button now should say "Download" and will warn you that you already have Mavericks installed. Clicking on the Download button should start it downloading.